# I am not sticky - what am I?

Tags: riddle

I am the second most acidic on the table,
but taste like nothing if you ever lick me.

I might be more filthy than you think,
but you let me kiss you on the cheek.

for you are the creator of my kind,
yet few have found not prays to me.

What am I?

Comment: Should it actually say "yet few have found not prays to me"?

Comment: @Quark I think it can be both a statement and a question, so both of us are correct!

Comment: Some kind of oil?

Comment: @Alex I actually was asking if that line was supposed to be that way grammatically, not if it could be phrased as a question. I'm even more confused now though if you say it could be phrased as a question as is.

Comment: @Quark sorry for mistaken your comments, to answer your origin question, yes it actually says what it was saying.  I suppose the riddle is more confusing than the riddlings it has =D

Comment: @Drux nope not oil, as the title stated, it's not sticky

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> A cell phone.

I am the second most acidic on the table,

> The most acidic would have a pH of 0, with the second most having a pH of 1. pHone.

but taste like nothing if you ever lick me.

> Phone screens don't have a taste to them.

I might be more filthy than you think,

> There are a lot of studies out there about how our cell phones have more germs than we could imagine on them.

but you let me kiss you on the cheek.

> When you talk on it, your phone is touching, or 'kissing' your cheek.

For you are the creator of my kind,

> Cell phones are man-made.

yet few have found not prays to me.

> When you hold your phone up to text, it looks a little bit like you're worshiping or praying to your phone.

Comment: +1 for a clever answer, though technically there's some frightening stuff hanging out in the negative PHs (especially around -31)

Comment: Nicely done!  Also @ShawnHolzworth it's referring to the PH table, so let's don't go to the too acidic zones =D

Comment: Thanks @Alex! This was driving me crazy yesterday. I had a good idea this was the answer but the first clue was stumping me. As soon as I figured that one out, I knew I had it right. Good riddle! (:

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is

> Oxygen

I am the second most acidic on the table,

> Oxygen is immediately adjacent to Fluorine - the most acidic element - on the periodic table

but taste like nothing if you ever lick me.

> Oxygen is flavourless (and odourless)

I might be more filthy than you think,

> All the Oxygen atoms in the atmosphere have been breathed in and out of countless lungs

but you let me kiss you on the cheek.

> Oxygen is the second largest component of the atmosphere - it brushes our cheeks all the time

for you are the creator of my kind,

> Not sure about this line - it might refer to the fact that humans have constructed the periodic table?

yet few have found not prays to me.

> I can't parse this line, either.

Comment: Could have been another answer to this riddle but second last line wouldn't fit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's

> face powder?

*I am the second most acidic on the table,

 but taste like nothing if you ever lick me.*

> I'll take your word for it!

*I might be more filthy than you think,*

> Who knows what horrible chemicals it's got in it.

*but you let me kiss you on the cheek.*

> It's often applied to cheeks.

*for you are the creator of my kind,*

> It's man-made.

*yet few have found not prays to me.*

> I can't really parse this line.

Comment: @randalthor Not the answer I am looking for but it does fits with some of the lines!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be:

> Saliva

I am the second most acidic on the table,
but taste like nothing if you ever lick me.

> Stomach acid is the most acidic thing in the human body, and I recall reading somehwere the saliva can be acidic too, so perhaps it takes second place. It also doesn't taste like anything, usually.

I might be more filthy than you think,
but you let me kiss you on the cheek.

> Saliva is usually full of mucus compunds and bacteria, and a big, wet, sloppy kiss on the cheek will transfer some to your face.

for you are the creator of my kind,
yet few have found not prays to me.

> Humans naturally create saliva. The second line is a knotty one - perhaps a reference,  to 'say it, don't spray it'?

Regardless, I highly recommend regular brushing and some mouthwash as a part of your daily routine.

Comment: Good guess but not the answer!